# Make the error shorter

Tags: c#, exception

I made a program in c#(I don't put here the code because there are lot of classes),and I made Exceptions to throw the mistakes,and when a mistake occurs this is what appears in the console:

> System.Exception: Student whit id:1 already exists!    at
>   StudentManagment.Service.AbstractService`4.Add(E entity) in
>   C:\Users\Robbi\source\repos\StudentManagment\StudentManagment\Service\AbstractService.cs:line
>   34    at StudentManagment.Domain.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\Users\Robbi\source\repos\StudentManagment\StudentManagment\Program.cs:line
>   23

And my question is, How can I  make that in the console to appear just

> Student whit id:1 already exists!

Comment: catch it - put out only the error ..

Comment: Use a try/catch, `try { ... } catch (Exception ex) { Console.Write(ex.Message); }`

Comment: Other than catching the exception, it is up to the user to determine the level of error information.

Comment: Go in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch)

Comment: You are most likely using `Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString())`, use `ex.Message` instead

Comment: _"I made Exceptions to throw the mistakes"_ - it's not good practice to use exceptions to control program flow. Exceptions should only be thrown in **exceptional** circumstances - an actual error occurred, the database server is on fire etc. I would suggest using return values instead.

Answer (score 1):

Catch the exception into a variable and output the `exception.Message` only. You are seeing a stack trace - ie all the methods that are in execution at the point of error. StackTraces are useful for debugging purposes, but not so great for displaying information to a user.

i.e

```
try 
{
   //do error here
}
catch(Exception e)
{
   Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very beginner issue

While you show no code, heres some semi fake code to answer the question

```
try
{
  do_it();
}
catch (Exception myEx) // you can do different things with different exception types
{
  Console.WriteLine("Error: "+myEx.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
ex.Message
```

where ex is your exceptption, something like

```
try 
{ 
    ...
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{ 
    Console.Write(ex.Message); 
}
```

Of course, edit this minimal snippet code to satisfy your needs